# run task on windows task scheduler every n minutes but the duration of the task is longer

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-task-scheduler, task-scheduler

i want to a task on windows scheduler to run every 10 minutes, but the duration of the task to complete is 15 minutes. So it will look like this:
10th minute -> 1st task start,
20th minute -> 2nd task schedule,
25th minute -> 1st start end,
next -> ?

when the 1st task ends, will it run the 2nd task or skip the 2nd and run the 3rd on the 30th minute ?

p.s. i want it to run the 2nd task immediately.

can i use one of the checkbox here ? which one ?
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTebE.png)

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that both options in provided screenshot cannot achieve your goal.

If you need run the task every 10 minutes, just try to set **Repeat task every: 10 minutes** as below attached screen. Then the task will be triggered every 10 minutes regardless of the task duration.

[image]

Comment: Hmm... how come it is 'One time' and not 'Daily'? 